# Configmap data is blank

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am creating a ConfigMap using this YAML file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Values.configmapName}}-config"
  labels:
    app: "{{ .Values.configmapName}}"
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "configmap/dev/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

The ConfigMap gets created but there is no data, the ConfigMap is blank.  I have multiple files under a `configmap/dev/` directory located at the root level of my Helm chart.  I'm expecting to see the data from the files which are under this `configmap/dev/` directory.

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with this, but I think you might want to be doing ```{{ .Files.AsConfig "configmap/dev/*" | indent 2 }}```

https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/

Comment: This is not working
<.Files.AsConfig>: wrong number of args for AsConfig: want 0 got 1

Comment: This line should work, assuming the files are present at myChart/configmap/dev/  .
This might be a mounting issue, could you share how you mount this configmap exactly? You are not mounting it next to secrets or under a folder that has secrets mounted in it right?

Comment: I fixed it by using this:

data:
{{ printf "configmap/config.yaml" | .Files.Get | indent 2 }}

Thanks for your help.